VS Code GUI glitching
I just so happened to be on the mood for code, but once I'm on the app this is what happened:

It's just line over line over time. But when I hover over the line, it disappears and goes back to normal, but just in that section only.
How do I fix this? I can't code like this.

Try to reboot.
If the problem isn't solved:
Follow the steps in
https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_40#_disable-gpu-acceleration
to disable hardware acceleration.
If the problem isn't solved:
Try to update the GPU drivers.
If the problem isn't solved:
Try to reinstall the VSCode.
If the problem isn't solved:
I ran out of ideas.
